# How do I get the copied value on onCopy event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose I have a long string:

```
"Jackie has a very big chicken at his farm"
```

And I highlight "chicken" from the string and hit ctrl+C,

It will trigger the `handleCopy` function passed into `onCopy` attribute of the element. I want to have the value of the substring or string being copied, in this case, "chicken" For example,

```
function handleCopy(event){
     //get the copied value here
}

<input value="Jackie has a very big chicken at his farm" onCopy={handleCopy} />
```

How am I able to achieve this in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [copy event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/copy_event) and the `getSelection` method on it as shown in the docs example ...

**A sample e.g. below**

```js
const App = () => {
  function handleCopy(event) {
    const selection = document.getSelection();
    console.log(selection.toString())
  }
  return (
    <input
      defaultValue="Jackie has a very big chicken at his farm"
      onCopy={handleCopy}
    />
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```